# I can´t export the animation that i import from maya into .glb

Tags: animation, export, error

i dont have any problem exporting the animation if i created on blender, but this is from an fbx that i import.
On blender it seem good, but i dont know how to export correctly. I do it with the menu "export", but it seems like an static characer.  Can you help me?

Comment: Just to be clear .. you imported an animation, it plays OK in Blender. But if you  re-export it, it doesn't play?

Comment: Yes, it doesn´t. I tried exporting with different option of the menu but is the same result.